# Chromecast pluggin for cordova fails to install

Tags: android, cordova, chromecast

I am trying to write a chromecast app with cordova

I have the android sdk installed, cordova v 4.1.2

I ran this command cordova plugin add https://github.com/GetVideostream/cordova-chromecast.git

```
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/GetVideostream/cordova-chromecast.git" via git clone
Installing "acidhax.cordova.chromecast" for android
Found Android SDK at /opt/android-sdk-linux
Executing /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update lib-project -p ./platforms/android/AppCompatLib ...
Failed to install 'acidhax.cordova.chromecast':Error: spawn EMFILE
        at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
        at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:935:11)
        at exports.spawn (child_process.js:723:9)
        at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:607:15)
        at exports.exec (child_process.js:578:18)
        at execCommand (/home/tholum/Documents/Projects/MyApp/plugins/acidhax.cordova.chromecast/init-playservices-dependencies.js:44:13)
        at prepareLibraryProject (/home/tholum/Documents/Projects/MyApp/plugins/acidhax.cordova.chromecast/init-playservices-dependencies.js:73:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tholum/Documents/Projects/MyApp/plugins/acidhax.cordova.chromecast/init-playservices-dependencies.js:170:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    Error: spawn EMFILE
        at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
        at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:935:11)
        at exports.spawn (child_process.js:723:9)
        at Object.exports.execFile (child_process.js:607:15)
        at exports.exec (child_process.js:578:18)
        at execCommand (/home/tholum/Documents/Projects/MyApp/plugins/acidhax.cordova.chromecast/init-playservices-dependencies.js:44:13)
        at prepareLibraryProject (/home/tholum/Documents/Projects/MyApp/plugins/acidhax.cordova.chromecast/init-playservices-dependencies.js:73:5)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tholum/Documents/Projects/MyApp/plugins/acidhax.cordova.chromecast/init-playservices-dependencies.js:170:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer of the plugin here! I see you've already fixed the issue. For reference the resolution link:
https://github.com/GetVideostream/cordova-chromecast/issues/38

Comment: Ya, I added the bug there as well, when I figured it out I forgot to close out this out as well